# Passing variables into command line arguments in rust through cmd shell in Windows

Tags: rust

I am trying to pass a variable as a part of a cmd command in my Rust program.

```
let path : String = "/home/directory/".to_string();
let  _command = Command::new("cmd")
                  .arg("-c")
                  .arg("mv somefile.txt '%0'") // is this the correct way?
                  .arg(&path)
                  .stdout(Stdio::piped())
                  .spawn()
                  .expect("Cannot be executed")
                  .wait();
```

The following program does not display the right path as desired. Would like to know how to pass variables from the Rust environment directly into the argument especially in the cmd environment.

Comment: Are you trying to execute `mv somefile.txt /home/directory/` in CMD? You don't have valid syntax for Command Prompt, but it could be done in PowerShell (with some changes) if you just need a Windows shell. Can you clarify your end goal?

Comment: `.arg(&format!("mv somefile.txt '{}'", path))`

Answer (score 1):

No it isn't the correct way; there is no magic in `.arg`, it only takes a simple string argument. No processing happens; a `%0` just stays a simple `%0`.

If you want an argument to be passed in, you have to create the string yourself, like with the [`format`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.format.html) macro:

```rust
let path : String = "/home/directory/".to_string();
let  _command = Command::new("cmd")
                  .arg("-c")
                  .arg(&format!("mv somefile.txt '{}'", path))
                  .stdout(Stdio::piped())
                  .spawn()
                  .expect("Cannot be executed")
                  .wait();
```

---

I'm unsure what your exact usecase is, so of course it could be that your example is just for demonstration purposes, but if this is actually what you are doing with it, there are better ways to achieve a file copy.

For one, I don't see the point of wrapping your execution in a `cmd`, couldn't you just use `mv` directly?

```rust
let path: String = "/home/directory/".to_string();
let _command = Command::new("mv")
    .arg("somefile.txt")
    .arg(&path)
    .stdout(Stdio::piped())
    .spawn()
    .expect("Cannot be executed")
    .wait();
```

Further, there is simpler ways to move files than to invoke `Command`:

```rust
let path = Path::new("/home/directory/");
std::fs::rename("somefile.txt", path.join("somefile.txt")).unwrap();
```